# Elegant alternative to if statements to output variables in PHP

Tags: php

Looking for an elegant approach in PHP to take in a variable and then output two preset values.

Instead of using a series of if statements like below, wondering if there is a more elegant solution.

Example:

```
if ($edit_array[1] == job) {
$table = 'jobs'; $id = 'job_id';
}
```

Comment: That's too small an example. There are many different ways to write conditional logic, all with different pros and cons. What's best suited for the situation depends on the situation, of which you show very little.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a bunch of ifs/elseifs try replacing them with [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)

```
switch( $edit_array[1] ) {
    case 'job':
        $table = 'jobs';
        $id = 'job_id';
    default:
    ...
}
```

or sometimes a simple "config" array works

```
$job_config = array(
   'job' => array(
        'table' => 'jobs',
        'id' => 'job_id'
    )
);

$job_info = $job_config[$edit_array[1]];
```

Comment: Thanks so much. The switch example is perfect because I only want the variables for the selected case.

Comment: Also remember the ever useful "extract" command... if you want the actual variables to be set just extract the relevant line from $job_config

Answer (score 0):

Try a [switch/case](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) section. Maybe without breaks.